# C++. Количество слов, имеющих n буквы

Tags: c++, строки

Всем привет! Не получается посчитать количество слов имеющих символы 'n' и 'b'. Т.е., нужно сосчитать количество слов имеющие обе эти буквы.
   С одной буквой еще понятно, но вот как две найти.
Нашел функцию find, но как понял, она ищет подстроки

```
string name;
    vector<string> str;
    int sum = 0;

while (cin >> name) {
    if (name == "0") {
        name.clear();
        break;
    }
    /*if (name.find('b') && name.find('n')) {
        sum++;
    }*/

    str.push_back(name);
}
for (int j = 0; j < str.size(); j++) {
    cout << str[j] << "\n" ;
}
cout << sum;
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, задание старое, просто вспомнил что тогда не смог решить, а интересно все-таки:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find()` здесь подходит, но вы используете ее неправильно.

Она возвращает не `true` или `false`, а позицию в строке (или `string::npos`, он же `-1`, если ничего не нашел).

Нужно так:

```
if (name.find('b') != string::npos && name.find('n') != string::npos)
```